# given a positive integer $n\geq 2$, we have a positive integer $m$ such that $m+2,m+3,\dots m+n$ are composite. (TIFR exam $2012$)

Tags: recreational-mathematics

Question is to prove that :

given a positive integer $n\geq 2$, we have a positive  integer $m$ such that $m+2,m+3,\dots m+n$ are composite.

I tried checking for small numbers to see if there is any pattern...

for $n=3$,  i have $m=6$ with  $m+2=8,m+3=9$ are composite

for $n=4$,  i have $m=12$ with  $m+2=14,m+3=15,m+4=16$ are composite

for $n=5$,  i have $m=23$ with  $m+2=25,m+3=26,m+4=27,m+5=28$ are composite

I do not see any pattern which assure me existence of $m$ for a general $n$

I would be thankful if some one can help me out with some hint.. Thank you

Comment: You may choose $m=n!$.

Comment: how come???????

Comment: $k$ divides $n!+k$ for $k=2,\dots,n$.

Comment: @Landscape : This is excellent... :) $n!+2$ has $2$ as factor,$n!+3$ has $3$ as factor... $n!+n$ has $n$ as factor :) :) wonderful...

Comment: @Landscape yes yes, just now i realized that...

Comment: I don't know the optimal upper bound of $m$, but at least $n!$ could be replaced by the product of all primes no more than $n$. By the way, would you mind posting an answer by yourself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $m=n!$ we have:

$n!+2$ has $2$ as factor. So, it is composite.

$n!+3$ has $3$ as factor. So, it is composite.

In general,

$n!+k$ has $k$ as factor (for $k \leq n$). So, it is composite.

This means $n!+2,n!+3,\dots,n!+n$ are composite.

Thus, given a positive integer $n\geq2$, we have a positive integer $m$ such that $m+2,m+3,\dots,m+n$ are composite.

Comment: You should probably mark this as "community wiki" as the answer was given by [Landscape](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/46120/landscape).

Comment: i have no idea what is community wiki :O